# Unity WebGL Facebook SDK share-link issue

Tags: c#, unity-webgl

Using Facebook SDK with Unity WebGL, when user try to press share link and Photo button i am getting below error in browser.

Button is Attached to following code:

```
if (this.Button("Share - Link Photo"))
            {
                FB.ShareLink(
                    new Uri("https://developers.facebook.com"),
                    callback: this.HandleResult);
            }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbWzS.png)

Tried in every Browser.